# Could not find Erlang include directory on RaspberryPI

Tags: linux, erlang, elixir

I´ve installed Erlang and Elixir on my RaspberryPI according to [this guide](http://mattr.info/2016/03/08/elixir-1.2-raspberry-pi.html) (I´ve chosen Erlang 19.0 and Elixir 1.3).

Then I created a mix project with elixir_ale as a dependency. When I try to run the project I get the following error message:

```
Makefile:24: *** Could not find include directory for ei.h. Check that Erlang header files are available.  Stop.
```

A search for **ei.h** reveals that it is placed under **/opt/erlang/19.0/lib/erlang/usr/include/ei.h**.

What is an appropriate way to make the header files available for gcc/mix? I tried to copy the content of the erlang include folder into **/usr/include/** but this didn´t help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Makefile [L20-L24](https://github.com/fhunleth/elixir_ale/blob/master/Makefile#L20-L24) you can find out, that `elixir_ale` is searching for the header under the following paths:

```
/usr/local/lib/erlang /usr/lib/erlang
```

So you probably should place your header (or symlink) to

```
/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include/ei.h
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. Since also *.a files were needed I linked them in the other directory that is searched by the Makefile. Unfortunately I couldn´t link the folders cause then **find** wouldn´t work as intended. So I symlinked the individual files.